# Are subqueries the only option to reuse variables?

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization, subquery

I'd like to use MySQL in this form:

```
SELECT 1 AS one, one*2 AS two
```

because it's shorter and sweeter than

```
SELECT one*2 AS two FROM ( SELECT 1 AS one ) AS sub1
```

but the former doesn't seem to work because it expects one to be a column.

Is there any easier way to accomplish this effect without subqueries?

And no, `SELECT 2 AS two` is not an option. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select @one := 1 as one, 2 * @one as two;
```

[user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

Comment: Great, thank you. No day has been passed without learning a new thing.

Answer (score 3):

Considering this SQL code

```
SELECT 1 AS one, one*2 AS two
```

from the perspective of SQL the language (and why not; mysql has a good track record of compliance with the ISO/ANSI SQL Standards), your `one` is not a variable; rather it is a column correlation name. You cannot use the correlation name in the `SELECT` clause with the same scope, hence the error.

FWIW your 'shorter and sweeter' syntax does actually work when using the MS Access Database Engine -- is that where you learned it, perchance? Sadly, the Access Database Engine has a poor track record of compliance with the Standards. It is said to take a long time to un-learn Access-speak and learn SQL code ;)

Comment: No, I actually hate Access-speak, so I didn't have to unlearn it fortunately -- but my assumption came from programming-speak, which caused this misunderstanding. Thank you for your answer! It's rare to see insightful posts after an accepted answer.